# Don't display image link url

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm working with the Facebook NuGet package in VS 2017. I want to post to a users wall with text and a link to an image stored in AWS S3. Everything posts, but the image has s3.amazonaws.com written at the bottom. I provide a description, title and caption, but the url insists on being there. How do I get rid of it? Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm pulling my hair out!
This is my args dictionary:

```
{[message, Eddie in tie Eddie.]}
{[name, Eddie in tie]}
{[picture, https://s3.amazonaws.com/blah blah blah]}
{[link, https://s3.amazonaws.com/blah blah blah]}
{[description, Eddie in tie]}
{[caption, Eddie in tie]}
```

[image: Facebook post with error circled in red]

Comment: _“I provide a description, title and caption”_ - good for you, but also pointless of course, because Facebook removed those parameters a while ago. The only way to specify those values now are Open Graph meta tags returned by the URL that you are sharing. That of course requires that you first of all share an HTML document, and not the picture directly.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I didn't know they had been removed since they still exist in the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/page/feed).

Comment: First of all, that's the documentation for posting to a page feed, not a user's. But even if you scroll this page down a bit ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/page/feed#custom-image